# Avoid repeating code parts when doing a SQL insert statement, which takes data from one table, modifies it, and inserts into another?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the following code:

```
INSERT INTO EXCHANGE_MAIN3
    SELECT 

    CASE Type
        WHEN 'BUY' then
            CASE SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4) 
                WHEN ('NANO') THEN
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4)
                WHEN ('DATA') THEN
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4)  
                ELSE 
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,3)
            END
        WHEN 'SELL' then
            CASE SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-4,LENGTH(MARKET))
                WHEN ('NANO') then
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-3,LENGTH(MARKET))
                WHEN ('DATA') then
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-3,LENGTH(MARKET))
                ELSE
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-2,LENGTH(MARKET))
        END
    END     
    AS COIN_BOUGHT,

    CASE Type
        WHEN 'BUY' then
            CASE SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-4,LENGTH(MARKET))
                WHEN ('NANO') then
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-3,LENGTH(MARKET))
                WHEN ('DATA') then
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-3,LENGTH(MARKET))
                ELSE
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-2,LENGTH(MARKET))
        END

        WHEN 'SELL' then
        CASE SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4) 
                WHEN ('NANO') THEN
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4)
                WHEN ('DATA') THEN
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4)  
                ELSE 
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,3)
        END

    END     
    AS PAYMETHOD,

    ...

FROM EXCHANGE_RAW_BINANCE;
```

There a lot of repeated parts.

`SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4)` is repeated a lot.

`SUBSTR(MARKET,1,3)` is repeated a lot.

`LENGTH(MARKET)-4` is repeated a lot.

The block

```
CASE SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4) 
                WHEN ('NANO') THEN
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4)
                WHEN ('DATA') THEN
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,4)  
                ELSE 
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,1,3)
            END
```

is repeated twice

The block

```
WHEN 'SELL' then
            CASE SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-4,LENGTH(MARKET))
                WHEN ('NANO') then
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-3,LENGTH(MARKET))
                WHEN ('DATA') then
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-3,LENGTH(MARKET))
                ELSE
                    SUBSTR(MARKET,LENGTH(MARKET)-2,LENGTH(MARKET))
        END
```

is repeated twice.
Is there a way to not have to repeat these chunks of code?
any advice appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compute the repeated `CASE` expressions in a subquery first, and then reuse them:

```
INSERT INTO EXCHANGE_MAIN3
SELECT
    CASE Type WHEN 'BUY' THEN expr1 WHEN 'SELL' THEN expr2 END,
    CASE Type WHEN 'BUY' THEN expr2 WHEN 'SELL' THEN expr1 END,
    ...
FROM
(
    SELECT *,
        CASE SUBSTR(MARKET, 1, 4) WHEN ('NANO') THEN SUBSTR(MARKET, 1, 4)
                                  WHEN ('DATA') THEN SUBSTR(MARKET, 1, 4) 
                                  ELSE SUBSTR(MARKET, 1, 3) END AS expr1,
        CASE SUBSTR(MARKET, LENGTH(MARKET)-4, LENGTH(MARKET))
            WHEN ('NANO') THEN SUBSTR(MARKET, LENGTH(MARKET)-3, LENGTH(MARKET))
            WHEN ('DATA') THEN SUBSTR(MARKET, LENGTH(MARKET)-3, LENGTH(MARKET))
            ELSE SUBSTR(MARKET, LENGTH(MARKET)-2, LENGTH(MARKET)) END AS expr2
    FROM EXCHANGE_RAW_BINANCE
) t
```